# How to set CMD key-binding in Emacs?

Tags: macos, emacs, homebrew

I'm using Emacs in Mac OS X terminal, installed with homebrew.

My CTRL key is my C key, and the ALT key is Meta.

How would I define key-bindings for CMD key combinations?

For instance, I want to set CMD-(right arrow) to go to the end of the line.

---

EDIT

I've tried @nickcarlo's suggestions below

```
(setq mac-command-modifier 'super)
(global-set-key (kbd "s-<right>") 'move-end-of-line)
```

I don't think CMD key is being set to super properly, since I don't see `s-foo` in the mini-buffer as I would if I had typed `C-x` or `M-x` or anything. I noticed that CMD-right, when I have two terminal windows open, switches between the two terminal windows, so I thought that might be blocking any custom setting. However, I tried:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "s-9") 'move-end-of-line)
```

.. and CMD-9 still does nothing, except beep to tell me I've pressed something wrong.

Setting non-CMD key-combos seems to work fine, like:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-w") 'move-end-of-line)
```

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do this as long as you run Emacs inside a terminal. The Mac cmd modifier isn't passed through (and might even not be encodable in standard terminal protocols / character sets). If you want this to work you should think about running Emacs.app as an application.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can set it with something like:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "s-<right>") 'move-end-of-line)
```

"s" being the reference to your command key.

PS: I'm not on my mac right now so I'm not sure what exactly you need to write to set it to the specific keys you mentioned to move it to the end of line but command is represented by an s in emacs.

**EDIT**
Just tested this on my mac. This is the exact code you'd write (if you wanted to set it globally) to bind your command key + right arrow key to move your cursor to the end of line.

If the above doesn't work, you could also try

```
(global-set-key (kbd "\s <right>") 'move-end-of-line)
```

The difference between the one above and this one is that the above equates to CMD+right and this one equates to CMD and then release CMD and hit the right key. Both work on OS X on my system.

Also check out the following post to set your CMD as the super key in case your Emacs doesn't already register it as such:

http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_hyper_super_keys.html

Specifically, you can use the following code to set up your CMD key as Super:

```
(setq mac-command-modifier 'super)
```

Comment: Can't get that to work. I should say that I'm using Emacs Live - https://github.com/overtone/emacs-live .. however, I tried a plain vanilla emacs and still no result. This code - https://github.com/lest/emacs-config/blob/master/rc-hotkeys.el - seems to suggest the format should be <s-left> , but that still doesn't work. It's as if the binding just doesn't register.

Comment: @cannyboy I got my copy of Emacs from macports (port install emacs-app) Maybe that's why I can get it to work with the code above. I've never used Emacs Live so I'm not sure how it differs from the one I've got.

Comment: @cannyboy Once you write this line or any other line like this, move to the end of line and execute C-x C-e and see if it displays the name of the functionality in the mini-buffer below. You can also check your key bindings by doing C-h b and see if its listed there.

Comment: I added to my Q. I'm guessing it is not possible in the terminal, as Jon O mentions.

Comment: @cannyboy I see. I'm sorry, I assumed you were working on the Emacs-app.

Answer (score 7):

In Aquamacs, what worked for me is the following

```
(global-set-key (kbd "A-r") 'my-command)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was what I was looking for my Aquamacs :)

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: c-x c-f .emacs // opens .emacs file

Step 2: Add the following lines at the end of .emacs file

```
    ;; changing the command to control
    (setq mac-command-modifier 'control)
```

Step 3: Save .emacs file

Step 4: M-x eval-buffer //M-x = Alt-x // This evaluates .emacs buffer and reloads Emacs

Step 5: Try CMD-e to go to end of the line. // Now CMD acts like control

Step 6: Still CMD-e does't work restart Emacs.

Enjoy Using Emacs!

Comment: Wouldn't this set his command key as his Control key? I don't think that's what he intends to do.

Comment: I feel It is more comfortable to use cmd as cnt it saves lot of time and reduce little finger pain.

Comment: I understand that and it seems to be the general practice of the OS X Emacs community (not followed by me though since I have the CMD key bound to other operations). I was just saying that I don't think the posted intended to change his Meta operations to his CMD key.

Comment: The question he asked is " I want to set CMD-(right arrow) to go to the end of the line." in my post I suggested it is one of the best practice to use CMD as CNT. If he does't want to change his CMD key bindings then he can use your solution.

Comment: Lol. He also said: "My CTRL key is my C key, and the ALT key is Meta. How would I define key-bindings for CMD key combinations?" Which doesn't indicate he meant "How do I change my Control key to CMD." I'd be glad if your answer helps him. And I'm not saying that you delete your answer or anything. What I am saying is that if you know a solution to bind CMD keys, which is regarded as the Super key by Emacs for OS X, then that would not only help him but the rest of us as well. But like you said, he can accept either answer. Anyway, good luck around here.